# java html to xml saxbuilder jdom2

Tags: java, xml, jdom

I'm trying to convert a html to xml for pasrsing. I'm using jdom2 and even found
some sample code in the Internet, but SAXBuilder is deprecated and so it didn't work.

Here is the part of the code which is important.

```
        frInHtml = new FileReader("E:\\Dropbox/workspace/test.html");
        brInHtml Html = new BufferedReader(frInHtml);


     SAXBuilder saxBuilder = new SAXBuilder("org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup.Parser", false);

        org.jdom2.Document jdomDocument = saxBuilder.build(brInHtml);
        XMLOutputter outputter = new XMLOutputter();
        try {
            outputter.output(jdomDocument, System.out);
            fwOutXml = new FileWriter("E:\\Dropbox/workspace/Second.xml");
            bwOutXml = new BufferedWriter(fwOutXml);
            outputter.output(jdomDocument, bwOutXml);
            System.out.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
```

In the documentation it says http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom2/input/SAXBuilder.html its says that I should "use SAXBuilder(XMLReaderJDOMFactory) with XMLReaderSAX2Factory.XMLReaderSAX2Factory(boolean, String)"
but it don't know how to use it. I would appreciate any kind of help

Here is my output:
Exception in thread "main" org.jdom2.JDOMException: Unable to create SAX2 XMLReader.
    at org.jdom2.input.sax.XMLReaderSAX2Factory.createXMLReader(XMLReaderSAX2Factory.java:129)

Comment: here is the full outputCaused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup.Parser
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)

Comment: If the problem is about class not found then add the dependency jar at runtime. Use jar finder to locate the jar. http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/java/info/org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup.Parser

Answer (score 0):

you have to add this jar to your build path :

http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/jars/versionInfo/2828

:)